# combine multiple chars to an int

Tags: c

I have four unsigned chars, each containing a byte, that I want to combine together to form a single int32_t, where the bytes come one after another.

```
       unsigned char x1 = 0b11100111;
       unsigned char x2 = 0b00010101;
       unsigned char x3 = 0b10000110;
       unsigned char x4 = 0b00001111;
```

With the four chars above the int32_t should have a binary representation of `0b11100111000101011000011000001111`.

How can this be done in c?

Comment: The simple recipe (for 16 bits) is `(x1 << 8) | x2`.

Comment: You want to combine four unsigned 8bits into one signed 32 bit, with the MSBit of the MSByte is set (1). Are you aware of the effect that has on the signed result? Do you wan that bit to control whether the result is negative or positive?

Comment: better to use *unsigned* 32-bit int. Also you must cast to unsigned char, if `int` is 32 bits, otherwise behaviour is undefined.

Comment: `((uint32_t_)x1 << 24) | ((uint32_t_)x2 << 16) | ...  | x0 )` is close to the idea.

Comment: ah, so I guess I should actually use an uint32_t

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a series of shifts and bitwise OR operations:

```
uint32_t x = 0;
x |= (uint32_t)x1 << 24;
x |= (uint32_t)x2 << 16;
x |= (uint32_t)x3 << 8;
x |= (uint32_t)x4;
```

Since the bytes are unsigned, you should use an `uint32_t` for the destination, otherwise you run into implementation defined behavior if the high order bit is set.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like follows:

```
    #include <stdint.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
      unsigned char x1 = 0b11100111;
      unsigned char x2 = 0b00010101;
      unsigned char x3 = 0b10000110;
      unsigned char x4 = 0b00001111;
      int32_t x5 = x1;
      x5 <<= 8;
      x5 |= x2;
      x5 <<= 8;
      x5 |= x3;
      x5 <<= 8;
      x5 |= x4;

      printf("%d", x5);

    }
```

Comment: The left-most bit is the sign bit when dealing with signed integers, is it not? The OP did not state his intentions. He might want a signed integer after all, why not?

Comment: Left shifting into the sign bit is _undefined behavior_ (C11 §6.5.7 4) , meaning the compiler may make any code and bad thing may happen.  Using `uint32_t` avoids that.  Assigning a `uint32_t` to a `int32_t` is less problematic - it is "implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised." §6.3.1.3 3  rarely a problem.

Comment: That's interesting, I didn't know that. It's counter-intuitive and makes no sense though. "If E1 has  a  signed type  and  nonnegative  value,  and E1×2E2 is  representable  in  the  result  type,  then  that  is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined". Why would the behavior be undefined when the value is negative? I mean...the signed integer is supposed to hold negative values as well. Go figure.

Comment: Say you are the C King - what behavior would you define for `-1 << 1`, or `INT_MAX << 1` or `INT_MIN << 1`?  Would that work well with 2's complement, sign-magnitude, 1's complement integers?  Would this behavior make for less efficient code when `x >= 0`?

Comment: Computers use 2's complement right? Then -1 << 1 would result in -1. 1 << 32 would result in -2147483648 etc. Maybe I'm missing something here?

Comment: Computers use 2's complement right? --> certainly _most_ do.  `-1 << 1` would result in `-1`???  `1 << 32` --> `-2147483648` ???  I`d recommend testing these with your compiler.